# Who is the lady in Cube 2?

Tags: cube-2-hypercube

I was left puzzled by the end of **Cube 2: Hypercube**:

- Was she undercover?
- Why was she shot?

Me wonders if there is some explanation I missed, or if it was just deliberate <strike>non-sense</strike> mindfuck.

Answer (score 4):

The character was an agent for the government (as revealed in one of the alternate endings). Presumably she was shot once she was no longer needed after retrieving the information on the necklace.